find_program in cmake cannot find tool provided by another recipe
I have two components A and B and two recipes A.bb and B.bb
B has on his list RDEPENDS and DEPENDS to A.
Component A produces tool and install toolA with common known cmake command:
install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR})
where PROJECT_NAME=toolA

Component B on cmake level wants to find this command:
find_program(PROGRAM_CMD toolA REQUIRED)
if(NOT PROGRAM_CMD )
    message(FATAL_ERROR "toolA not found")
endif()

But it cannot find. I checked and there is none toolA in B recipe sysroot. toolA is in A recipe sysroot. So I added in B.bb:
do_configure[depends] += "A:do_populate_sysroot"

but there is still none toolA in B recipe sysroot and problem still exists.
Anyone knows how to do such magic that B can find the results of compilation of A (so toolA in this case)?
The above is simplified case for easier description that is why I used terms A, B, toolA etc.
My current workaround on A.bb level:
do_install_append() {
    install -m 0644 ${D}${bindir}/toolA ${WORKDIR}/../../toolAToShare
}

and on B.bb level I copy to B sysroots in do_install_prepend/do_prepare. But this is shitty. I would like to make in the way how world do, but what is good approach I don't have any idea. So please help if anyone knows how to do it properly.

find_program is used to find dependencies from the host machine. So, it's a completely wrong direction and you should not invest time in this Direction. I think Depends variable in Yocto can be helpful but let me have a look at it in detail

Have a look at this thread and try to do it. It seems relevant to your issue
https://lists.yoctoproject.org/g/yocto/topic/dependencies_between_recipes/84846545

In general yocto and bitbake serves to create linux distribution. It doesn't serves for the purpose that one recipe creates tool and another recipe can use it on cmake level. That is why for the first time I meet such case as I have none experience with such usage of yocto.
